# How to send image from android gallery to react-native app?

Tags: react-native

How do i share an image from android gallery to react-native app?

I've added an intent-filter to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

How do i listen to the send intent?

Edit: I want to send an image from native image gallery to my react-native app, like sharing an image from gallery to instagram app.

Comment: Have you read about [CameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html)

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think that CameraRoll can help me. It should be more like [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) but without url

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no builtin method to handle this. So i wrote a simple native android module by my own.

Finally i found an extension which supports ios and android.

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension