# How to handle send intent (share menu item) in react native app?

Tags: react-native

I have successfully configured iOS app to handle audio document types (not deeplinks!) so I can use share dialog to open audio files in my app, this works fine.

I have successfully configured Android `intent-filter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to hande audiofiles same way, this is also recognized fine by Android system and I see my app when I use share menu on audiofiles. However, Android implementation of `Linking` component seems to ignore `SEND` intent actions and only care about `View` intent actions as I saw on `IntentModule.java:55`:

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && uri != null) {
      initialURL = uri.toString();
    }
```

I tried to patch intent in my `MainActivity.java` to make it return same uri with `VIEW` action, but this always produces an error in runtime.

```
@Override
public Intent getIntent() {
    Intent origIntent = super.getIntent();
    if (origIntent != null && Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(origIntent.getAction())) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, origIntent.getData());
    }
    return origIntent;
}
```

However I always get an error indicating that `getData` is null.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41670541/2105993), but having a share extension is an overkill for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that Intent might contain additional information called `ClipData`, which can contain `Uri` as well. My luck was that I had exactly one `Uri` (I guess it can contain multiple `Uri` objects if I share multiple audiofiles at once. So this code worked, I can now share files to react native app

```
@Override
public Intent getIntent() {
    Intent origIntent = super.getIntent();
    if (origIntent != null && Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(origIntent.getAction())) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, this.uriFromClipData(origIntent.getClipData()));
    }
    return origIntent;
}

private Uri uriFromClipData(ClipData clip) {
    if (clip != null && clip.getItemCount() > 0) {
        return clip.getItemAt(0).getUri();
    }
    return null;
}
```